# Creating a subnet on AWS - CIDR Address overlaps with existing Subnet CIDR

Tags: amazon-web-services, cloud, cidr

I am trying to work on creating a subnet on AWS. This is the question I am stuck on:
Create a new subnet. Add it to the same VPC as the first subnet, and use an adjacent CIDR block. What CIDR block did you use?

My original VPC, I used 10.0.1.0/24, however; I keep getting this error
CIDR Address overlaps with existing Subnet CIDR: 10.0.1.0/24.

What would be an adjacent CIDR?

Thanks!

I have tried a lot of different ones, just to see and I either get the error message that it overlap or CIDR Address is not within CIDR Address from VPC.

Comment: What is the CIDR of the VPC?

Comment: It is 10.0.1.0/24

Comment: If your VPC is 10.0.1.0/24, and it already has a subnet of 10.0.1.0/24, then there's no room for a new subnet.  You'll need to replace the VPC with a larger one that can have smaller subnets inside of it.